# Magento Fatal error: Cannot declare trait Magento\Framework\Interception\Interceptor

Tags: php, magento

I got error after scanning the website with cpanel scanner.

Fatal error: Cannot declare trait Magento\Framework\Interception\Interceptor, because the name is already in use in /home/..../public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/State/Interceptor.php on line 19.

I have tried all answers related to this  but no luck. I have update code from fresh Interceptor file as well but still same error.

Please help me to reolve this.
Link is  https://www.advcylinderheads.com/
Many Thanks

Comment: Your website seems ok and what is cpanel scanner, do you mean the virus scanner?

You can remove `generated` folder and run `bin/magento setup:di:compile` to generate them again (in your local host I think because you don't have access to ssh in sharing hosts)

Comment: Yes i have run these commands and it works. Cpanel scanner is a malware scanner which quarntine the Interceptor.php file. Thank you for your reply.